# How to change the least significant bit in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I'm new in Python and I would like to know how to change the least significant bit in Python.

I would like to do something like this:

```
mybytes = bytes(16) ## Creating the byte object filled with zeros
mybytes[0] = 1 ## Changing the least significant bit
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `mbytes`variable is supposed to represent what? A 128 bit integer?

Comment: `bytes` is a byte string, it's not intended for addressing individual bits.

Comment: `mybytes[0]` is a byte, not a bit.

Comment: Byte strings are immutable, just like character strings, you can't assign to an element.

Comment: @guidot Yes, it is supposed to represent a 128 bit integer.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I wrote mybytes[0] just to illustrate what I want.

Comment: Use a list instead of bytes. Then you can do `mybytes[0] |= 1` to set the least significant bit of the least significant byte.

Comment: `mybytes = [0] * 16`

Comment: ```foo = bytes(16)``` and then ```foo = [x ^ 1 if i == len(foo)-1 else x for i, x in enumerate(foo)]``` then  ```foo = bytes(foo)```

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers ! :)